# Double for loop on a range to get the emails from a column and to compose a table for that email (GAS)

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The data is like this, basically:

```
 Activity    Deadline   Responsible         Status
 Activity1   09/20/2020 some@gmail.com      In progress
 Activity2   10/10/2020 someother@gmail.com Finished
```

The code below loops through Responsible column to create a unique set of emails and then it loops through the data range to create a table containing the activities pending different than Cancelled and Finished, which will then be sent to each of the email in the am set of email to remember them which activities are waiting for their input/update.

Despite the piece where I compare the first responsible with the one from the second loop, the activities composing the tables are not separated correcltly.
One recipient gets his activities, but the other gets all of the activities and the email is sent twice to the latter.
Here is the log output for both loops/columns compared:
[image]

If you could shed a light here, that would be greatly appreciated:

```js
function emailPendingActivity() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Atividades");
  var startRow = 9;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 24);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  //This creates the history table headers
  var historyMsg = "<html>"
  + "<h2 style='color:darkred;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;'>Atividades Pendentes</h2>"
  + "<body>"
  + "<table style=\"text-align:center\">"
  + "<tr style='color:darkred;font-size:12px;'>"
  + "<th>N°</th>"
  + "<th>Solicitante</th>"
  + "<th>Projeto</th>"
  + "<th>Natureza</th>"
  + "<th>Área</th>"
  + "<th>Atividade</th>"
  + "<th>Status</th>"
  + "<th>Prazo</th>"
  + "<th>Dias de Atraso</th>";
  
  //This gets unique responsible people from Atividades sheet
  var responsibles = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; ++j) {
    var rowResp = data[j];
    responsibles.push(rowResp[7]);
  }
  var unique = (value,index,self) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index
  }
  var uniqueResp = responsibles.filter(unique);
  
  for (var n = 0; n < uniqueResp.length;++n) {
    if (uniqueResp[n] != ''){
      var respRow = uniqueResp[n];

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var rowData = data[i];
        var activityNo = rowData[0];
        var resp = rowData[7];
        var status = rowData[11];
        //if ((status.indexOf('Concluído') == -1) || (status.indexOf('Cancelado') == -1)) {
        if (activityNo != '') {
        if (status != 'Concluído') {
        if (status != 'Cancelado') {
        if (resp === respRow){
          Logger.log('resp: ' + resp);
          Logger.log('respRow: ' + respRow);
              Logger.log(status)
              var solicitante = rowData[2];
              var nature = rowData[3];
              var project = rowData[4];
              var area = rowData[5];
              var activity = rowData[6];
              var deadline = rowData[9];
              var statusDays = rowData[13];
              //var deadlineAsDate = Utilities.formatDate(deadline, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
              historyMsg += "<tbody>"
              + "<tr>"
              + "<td>" + activityNo + "</td>"
              + "<td>" + solicitante + "</td>"
              + "<td style=\"text-align:center\">" + nature + "</td>"
              + "<td style=\"text-align:center\">" + project + "</td>"
              + "<td style=\"text-align:center\">" + area + "</td>"
              + "<td style=\"text-align:left\">" + activity + "</td>"
              + "<td style=\"text-align:center\">" + status + "</td>"
              + "<td style=\"text-align:center\">" + deadline + "</td>"
              + "<td style=\"text-align:center\">" + statusDays + "</td>"
              + "</tr>";
            }
          }
        }
        }
      }
      
    var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
    + historyMsg;
    + "</HTML></BODY>"

    var subject = "Some subject";
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      name: "Specific Name",
      to: respRow,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message
    });
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: *Despite the piece where I compare the first responsible with the one from the second loop, the activities composing the tables are not separated correcltly and I may be missing something.* Explain with current output and expected output.

Comment: Just added it to the problem, @TheMaster!

Comment: I got that already. I'm asking what  tangible thing you see that makes you think that something is wrong?

Comment: Ah! I have 02 emails as recipients. But the rows appended in the email are correct for one reciepient. The other is getting all of the rows; not just his. Would that be then the way MailApp / to: is written, @TheMaster?

Comment: [Edit] that into your question. Also provide representative values  of logs: `Logger.log('resp: ' + resp);
          Logger.log('respRow: ' + respRow);
              Logger.log(status)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You are instantiating the `historyMsg` variable outside the for-loop. Basically you will append every row to this previously instantiated HTML table. You can't continue to append the values if you want to send only the corresponding one to the correct email address.

You should instantiate a new `historyMsg` for each `uniqueResp` element. So that the table will be build accordingly to your `if` conditions.

### Proposed modification

```
function emailPendingActivity() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Atividades");
  var startRow = 9;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 24);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  //Move this into the for loop so it will create a unique message for each recipient
  /**var historyMsg = "<html>"
  + "<h2 style='color:darkred;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;'>Atividades Pendentes</h2>"
  + "<body>"
  + "<table style=\"text-align:center\">"
  + "<tr style='color:darkred;font-size:12px;'>"
  + "<th>N°</th>"
  + "<th>Solicitante</th>"
  + "<th>Projeto</th>"
  + "<th>Natureza</th>"
  + "<th>Área</th>"
  + "<th>Atividade</th>"
  + "<th>Status</th>"
  + "<th>Prazo</th>"
  + "<th>Dias de Atraso</th>";*/
  
  //This gets unique responsible people from Atividades sheet
  var responsibles = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; ++j) {
    var rowResp = data[j];
    responsibles.push(rowResp[7]);
  }
  var unique = (value,index,self) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index
  }
  var uniqueResp = responsibles.filter(unique);
  
  for (var n = 0; n < uniqueResp.length;++n) {
    if (uniqueResp[n] != ''){
      var respRow = uniqueResp[n];
       //This creates the history table headers
      var historyMsg = "<html>"
      + "<h2 style='color:darkred;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;'>Atividades Pendentes</h2>"
      + "<body>"
      + "<table style=\"text-align:center\">"
      + "<tr style='color:darkred;font-size:12px;'>"
      + "<th>N°</th>"
      + "<th>Solicitante</th>"
      + "<th>Projeto</th>"
      + "<th>Natureza</th>"
      + "<th>Área</th>"
      + "<th>Atividade</th>"
      + "<th>Status</th>"
      + "<th>Prazo</th>"
      + "<th>Dias de Atraso</th>";

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
...
```

Comment: Awe - f'ng - some!

Comment: Quick question:
Why is this sending the message twice to one of the recipient? Gracias!

Comment: It's not. Can you check if the `unique` function is working correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is. Here's the log: [santosonit@gmail.com, antocle@email.com.br, ]  The second recipient is the one getting the mesage twice. The first message contains some rows and the second contains those rows appended twice.

Comment: Found it. I had left the if (uniqueResp[n] != ''){ closed before the second loop. Just closed it after the message is sent and it is correct now. These are the bumps I gotta go through when learning. Thank you very much!